# PHP storing the awk result to break down into more analytic

Tags: php, awk

I'm collecting some information from the apache logs, and passing over for graph/dashboard purpose.
Currently, i've multiple filter to extract from the logs, but i realize if my solution keeps on expanding I would have issue because each time i've to open the file and run through a loop to get the expected .
This is the working solution :-

```
$extract_log = "awk -v d1=\"$(date --date=\"-5 min\" \"+%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S\")\" -v d2=\"$(date \"+%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S\")\" 'substr($4,2) > d1 && substr($4,2) < d2 || substr($4,2) ~ d2' /xampp/timing_log | awk  'substr($7,2,8) ~  /apollo/'  | grep -v 'session'  | awk -F  '\"' '{print substr($3,1,4)}' | sort | uniq -c ";

$extract_log2 = "awk -v d1=\"$(date --date=\"-5 min\" \"+%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S\")\" -v d2=\"$(date \"+%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S\")\" 'substr($4,2) > d1 && substr($4,2) < d2 || substr($4,2) ~ d2' /xampp/timing_log | awk  'substr($7,2,8) ~  /apollo/'  | grep -v 'x-frame'  | awk -F  '\"' '{print substr($3,1,4)}' | sort | uniq -c ";


$output = shell_exec($extract_log); // Works, return me the row of the timing logs + filtered data
$output2 = shell_exec($extract_log2); // Works, return me the row of the timing logs + filtered data
```

I'm trying to find the possibilities, while i hold the logs in a variable for example. Can i do like the following below ?

```
$extract_log = "awk -v d1=\"$(date --date=\"-5 min\" \"+%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S\")\" -v d2=\"$(date \"+%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S\")\" 'substr($4,2) > d1 && substr($4,2) < d2 || substr($4,2) ~ d2' /xampp/timing_log";

$extract_x_session="| awk  'substr($7,2,8) ~  /apollo/'  | grep -v 'session'  | awk -F  '\"' '{print substr($3,1,4)}' | sort | uniq -c";
$extract_x_frame="| awk  'substr($7,2,8) ~  /apollo/'  | grep -iv 'x-frame'  | awk -F  '\"' '{print substr($3,1,4)}' | sort | uniq -c";

$output = shell_exec($extract_log); // Works, return me the row of the timing logs
$second_output = shell_exec($output.$extract_log); // Failed
$third_output = exec($output.$extract_x_frame); // Failed
```

I'm still thinking is it possible for a variable to store the logs ? while append the other awk commands and extract from the php stored variable within PHP.

TLDR; First code run through the whole log twice to get the value, I want to achieve in a single code where I can store the variable of the logs and another variable to store the awk command to perform the awk .

Comment: I'd say that this mix of PHP and shell script/pipes makes this piece of code very difficult to maintain. Why don't you just read the entire log file with PHP and then process it with PHP as well?

Comment: @rethab, i guess that's my only options from the looks of it using foreach.